# Undefined Method error 'find(), find_by(), find_by_id(), where()' Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, quickbooks-online

I'm new on Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to assign attributes from one model to another. To be more specific, I'm trying to integrate my Ruby on Rails App with Quickbooks Online (using the [quickbooks-ruby gem](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby) by Ruckus). But I can't assign my companies(customers) to the quickbooks Customer model. I'm using `Ruby 2.7.2p137` and `Rails 6.0.3` OAuth process is complete and works fine.

I'm getting `Undefined method error 'find' for #<Quickbooks::Model::Customer:0x00007ff178b0ebd8>`  error. I'm %100 sure that I'm doing something awfully wrong but I can't figure out where. I tried to assign attributes to the quickbooks model with this code (running under a service class btw);

```py
    def qb_customers
      set_client #For setting the OAuth client works fine.
      service              = Quickbooks::Service::Customer.new
      service.access_token = @access_token 
      service.company_id   = @options[:realm_id] 
      companies            = Network::Company.all
      customer             = Quickbooks::Model::Customer.new
      i = 0
      companies.each do |company|
        comp = company.find(i)
        if comp.name == customer.display_name
          i += 1
        else
          customer.display_name                               = comp.name
          customer.primary_phone&.free_form_number            = comp.tel
          customer.mobile_phone&.free_form_number             = comp.gsm
          customer.fax_phone&.free_form_number                = comp.fax
          customer.primary_email_address&.address             = comp.email
          customer.web_site&.uri                              = comp.website
          customer.billing_address&.line1                     = comp.address
          customer.billing_address&.city                      = comp.city
          customer.billing_address&.country                   = comp.state
          customer.billing_address&.postal_code               = comp.postcode
          customer.billing_address&.country_sub_division_code = comp.country_id
          customer.billing_address&.lat                       = comp.latitude
          customer.billing_address&.lon                       = comp.longtude
          customer.notes                                      = comp.notes
          customer.save
        end
      end
      customers = service.query(nil, :page => 1, :per_page => 900000)
    end
```

Tried this block with `find_by()`, `find_by_id()`, `where()` as well but all of them returned Undefined Method Error.

So I tried a different approach;

```py
companies.each do |comp|
      if comp.name != customer.display_name
        customer.display_name                               = comp.name
        customer.primary_phone&.free_form_number            = comp.tel
        #same attributes here
        .
        .
        .
        customer.notes                                      = comp.notes
        customer.save
      else 
        next
      end
    end
```

This time I got `undefined method 'save' for #<Quickbooks::Model::Customer:0x00007ff178b0ebd8>` error. So I'm really stuck here I am not sure what's exactly wrong. Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is something fishy about this question. *"Undefined method error 'find' for #<Quickbooks::Model::Customer:0x00007ff178b0ebd8>"* Suggests that you call `find` on a `Quickbooks::Model::Customer` instance, yet the only `find` used in the question (first codeblock) is called on the `Network::Company.all` result (`companies`), which I assume returns an ActiveRecord relation, and not a `Quickbooks::Model::Customer` instance.

Comment: I ran it again as it is and it gives `undefined method 'find' for #<Network::Company:0x00007fdbf973d6b0>` Oops, I remember, I copied the bottom error with 'save' then changed it to find. I thought it wouldn't be a problem since both were undefined method errors but yeah I wasn't careful sorry about that.

Comment: Adittionally you instantiate the new `Quickbooks::Model::Customer` outside of the iteration... this results in only overwriting the previous data of the customer with the next one...

Comment: What is `Network::Company`? Did you define it yourself? Is it defined by some other gem? It seems like it isn't a ActiveRecord model, because in your previous comment you said that `Network::Company.all` returns `#<Network::Company:0x00007fdbf973d6b0>` whereas Rails models would return an ActiveRecord relation.

Comment: The error of the second code block is more obvious. The [`Quickbooks::Model::Customer`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/quickbooks-ruby/Quickbooks/Model/Customer) instance doesn't has a `save` method (it is not a Rails model instance). The readme on GitHub says you should update your object with [`service.update(customer)`](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby#updating-an-object).

Comment: Yes, thank you! As I dig through the gem's issues thread, I found it as well. You can post this an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your second code block is because `customer` is an `Quickbooks::Model::Customer` instance. You currently treat it like an ActiveRecord model instance, which it isn't. When we look at the [documentation for this class](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/quickbooks-ruby/1.0.17/Quickbooks/Model/Customer), you can see there is no `save` method there.

The [GitHub readme](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/blob/v0.6.6/README.md#updating-an-object) provides us with the info you are looking for:

> ### Updating an object
>
> By default updating an object will un-set any attributes that are NOT
> specified in the update request. That is, the update is NOT sparse by
> default. Thus, be careful as you might accidentally unset attributes
> that you did not specify.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> # fetch a Customer to change their name
> customer = service.fetch_by_id("99")
> customer.company_name = "Neo Pets"
> service.update(customer)
> ```
>
> In the above example since we retrieved all fields and then just
> changed a single attribute, we have given the "complete" entity back
> to Intuit and effectively only the name is changed.
>
> If you don't have the complete object on hand and only want to change
> a couple of attributes without un-setting what you are not specifying
> than you want to use a sparse update:
>
> ```
> # update a Customer's name when we only know their ID
> customer = Quickbooks::Model::Customer.new
> customer.id = 99
> customer.company_name = "New Company Name"
> service.update(customer, :sparse => true)
> ```

So you should use `service.update(customer)` to instead of `customer.save` to update the data.

---

Since you didn't provide any info about the `Network::Company` class and it is not part of the "quickbooks-ruby" gem I can't help you with the first code block. If you wish to solve that problem you'll have to provide some more details.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend a read of https://dev.to/adamlombard/ruby-class-methods-vs-instance-methods-4aje .

Essentially `find_by()` `find_by_id()` `where()` are class methods. You are trying to call them on instances of that class: `comp = company.find(i)`

Without knowing much about quickbook I'm sure the line needs to look like this

```rb
Network::Company.find(i)
```

Also worth mentioning that your already retrieved all of the `Network::Company`s with `companies = Network::Company.all` and when you iterate over them the information is already available and you don't need to retrieve them again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what should I do exactly? What kind of structure that I should use in order to assign these attributes. I tried replacing with `Network::Company.find(i)` but this time I get `undefined method 'each'` error.

Comment: I guess that a complete different issue and question. I can recommend to actually try to reduce your code to the actual problem and try to solve this. Stackoverflow isn't very well suited for debugging multiple problems and debugging help.

Comment: It's not 'debugging' or 'multiple problems' I just followed your suggestion and saw that it didn't work. The problem is the same, when I somehow bypass the error caused by `find()` methods I get a different error like `undefined method 'save'` So obviosly there's something different going on here.

Comment: Well then. Where does the `undefined method 'each'` come from?

Comment: From the `each do`  iteration, I guess.

Comment: What has changed exactly before the error occurred?

Comment: Well, I changed `comp = company.find(i)`  with this, `comp = Network::Company.find(i)` then removed the line `companies = Network::Company.all` as you suggested, which gave the `undefined method 'each'` error. I saw the problem after I sent the comment, `companies` was not defined since I removed it's assignment, so when I put the line back I get the error: `undefined method 'save'` this is where I stand right now.

Comment: Since you removed `companies = Network::Company.all` (which I didn't recommend, just hinted since you duplicate retrievals on the database) you can't iterate over anything since `companies` is `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

As we [can see here](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/blob/master/lib/quickbooks/model/base_model.rb), the "model" inside the gem isn't an `ApplicationRecord`, so it doesn't implement ActiveRecord methods like `find`, `where`, `save`.

The Customer model itself [is a parser of XML](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/blob/master/lib/quickbooks/model/customer.rb).

If you want to operate database operations, I recommend you to create your own `Customer` model and build from this object returned from `quickbooks` gem.